# Very slow linking of the Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, makefile, point-cloud-library

I am trying to follow the tutorial of the Point Cloud Library but I have run into a problem. The linking the PCL libraries take as much as 5 mins for a simple Hello World program. Granted this is a big library with many dependencies but I feel 5 mins is too long.

I have pasted my cmake file down. Maybe there is a simple point I am overlooking. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(cloud_viewer)

find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable (cloud_viewer cloud_viewer.cpp)
target_link_libraries (cloud_viewer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: My crystal ball guesses; you probably don't have as much RAM as the linker needs, so your system starts using swap and everything runs at a snails pace... Without more info that's all that the crystal ball can come up with.

Comment: I ran htop to see how much memory is consumed...The linking process is not taking much memory and I still have lot of RAM left.

Comment: On further experimentation linking PCL_IO_LIBRARIES seems the bottleneck